# Group by all columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with `iris` data.table in R.

To remind how it looks I paste six five rows here

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I would like to calculate the number of rows, grouped by all columns. Of course we may write all variables in `by`, like this:

```
iris[, .(Freq = .N), by = .(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species)]



   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Freq
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    1
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    1
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    1
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    1
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    1
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    1
```

However, I wonder if there is a method to *group by all variables* without needing to type all the columns names?

Comment: Please study the help text, `?data.table`: "`by` accepts ... a character vector of column names". Thus, `iris[, .N, by = names(iris)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach in Base-R

```
Freq <- table(apply(iris,1,paste0, collapse=" "))
iris$Freq <- apply(iris,1, function(x) Freq[names(Freq) %in% paste0(x,collapse=" ")])
```

output:

```
> iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Freq
...          ...         ...          ...         ...  ...        ...
140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica    1
141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica    1
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica    1
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica    2
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica    1
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica    1
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for duplicates, `uniqueN` will default to using all columns:

```
uniqueN(as.data.table(iris))
# [1] 149
```

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it might be a more direct way of accomplishing what you were trying to do in the first place.

Similarly, if you're looking for which rows are duplicated, you can use `duplicated`'s `data.table` method which similarly defaults to using all columns:

```
iris[duplicated(iris)]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1:          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
out1 <- as.data.table(iris)[, .N, by = names(iris)]
```

-checking with OP's approach

```
out2 <-  as.data.table(iris)[,  .N, by = .(Sepal.Length, 
      Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species)]
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```